# Unable to Filter Ghost Referrals in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-spam

I set up a view level filter to remove ghost referral spam where the filter field ie `Campaign Source` and `Filter Pattern` is something like `www.event-tracking\.com|Get-Free-Traffic-Now\.com`.

**Problem:** However it is unable to remove `www.event-tracking.com` and `Get-Free-Traffic-Now.com` although this method removed many others.

What is special about these 2 ghost referral spam and why are they not removed?

Answer (score 1):

They use a **vulnerability in Google Analytics** to make **fake visits** so the only way to stop them for now, and until Google fix it, is to make a **filter in GA** since that is the source of the problem.

Blocking them in the `.htaccess` file **is pointless** since this kind of Spam never visits your site.

Check this answers for more information **about this spam** https://stackoverflow.com/a/29312117/3197362

And this for **Referrer Spam in General** and some methods you can use **to filter them** and **stop future occurrences** https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362

As for the **previous/historical data**, you can use **segments** in Google analytics. Create a **REGEX** with the Spam names something like this:

```
social-buttons\.com|simple-share-buttons\.com
```

You can add as many as you want, but the REGEX has a 255 character limit. You can add multiple conditions if this happens

- Go to the **Reporting section** in your Google Analytics.
- In the lateral bar, expand **Acquisitions > All Traffic** and Select
  **Referrals**.
- In the main board Click on **+Add Segment**.
- Click on **New Segment**.
- Select **Conditions** Below Advanced.
- Set filter as **Exclude**. Change Ad Content for **Medium** and contains for
  exactly matches and type and select **referral** in the text box.
- Click on **AND**
- Change Ad Content for **Source** and contains for **matches regex** and paste
  the Spam Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping all the special characters in the expression

```
www\.event\-tracking\.com|Get\-Free\-Traffic\-Now\.com
```

There shouldn't be a problem filtering any referral if the expression matches it. Have you tried using a valid hostname filter instead.

One thing that all **ghost spam have in common is that they use either a fake hostname or they leave it as not set**, so if you create a filter with only your valid hostnames all ghost spam will be gone.

You can find more information about this solution in this related question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362

Answer (score 0):

In Google Analytics, you can import segments builds by other advanced users. Try to import segments according to your configuration.

To get such configured segment, go to Add Segment, then Import from Gallery
and apply search filter "spam bots".

You will get the lists of segments developed by the community and use them as per your configuration.

If you able to learn from custom segment, you can improve it with more data and settings and contribute back to the community

In Imported Segments, you can analyse settings, applied filters and used advanced segments to develop next version of complex segments. This is continuous learning process.